# Using WebClient or WebRequest perform button click on page

Tags: c#, webrequest

I need to perform button click on page with help of WebClient or WebRequest.
This button pure user side action to load html form with help of JavaScript.

```
<a id="TestMeLink_index" class="TestMeLink" href="#" onclick="form.start(33);return false;">TestMe</a>
```

After this link is clicked popup window with form is loaded.
My main task is to test this form is loaded to the page. Second task is submit this form after.
Page I am trying to work is static html page on IIS

Comment: am confused with your question. You are trying to click the button using `WebRequest`???

Comment: Yes, if it is possible, but main task is to test if user can see the form after the button click.